# How to update kubernetes job status of a job after being executed through swagger running a container deployment?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, swagger-ui, minikube, kubernetes-jobs

i have deployed my front end application through a `deployment.yaml` file using minikube having `swagger-ui` . This application simply takes in json queries and starts jobs on minikube which runs and terminates relevant containers. 
currently i have built 1 docker image on my minikube cluster which starts downloading satellite images after the job is started. 
Now whenever i pass a json query to swagger-ui, it gives me the following  response where the job status is `PENDING`:

```
{
  "workflowId": "2a94d0e3-7245-47e4-a9ce-821efce42eb8",
  "workflowName": "monitoring1",
  "status": "PENDING",
  "submittedAt": "2019-08-29T08:22:59.599469Z",
  "completedAt": null,
  "jobs": [
```

**Job watcher**

```
var jobStatus = JobStatus.PENDING
        when (action) {
            Watcher.Action.ADDED -> {
                if (job.status.startTime != null && job.status.active >= 0) {
                    jobStatus = JobStatus.RUNNING
                }
            }
            Watcher.Action.MODIFIED -> {
                if (job.status.completionTime != null && job.status.succeeded >= 0) {
                    jobStatus = JobStatus.COMPLETED
                } else if (job.status.failed != null) {
                    jobStatus = JobStatus.ERROR
                }
            }
            Watcher.Action.DELETED -> {
                log.info("DELETED")
            }
            Watcher.Action.ERROR -> {
                jobStatus = JobStatus.ERROR
            }
        }
```

on the minikuber side, the job starts and terminates after some time but on the side of swagger, the status of job never changes. However, when i try to run a `GET` query to list all jobs, there i see the completed job. **My question is how can i update status or notify the user once the job completes?**.

Answer (score 0):

It might be how the question is worded, but after starting a job, is expected to get a `PENDING` status as the immediate response, as the job hasn't finished yet. Furthermore, it looks like you're using `GET` to query the status of the job afterwards, which will also result in the expected behavior.

Now, Swagger has support for [long polling via callbacks](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/callbacks/) and the Kubernetes API has read [support for the verb `WATCH`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/):

> Watch will stream results for an object(s) as it is updated. Similar to a callback, watch is used to respond to resource changes.

This feature also extends to your [specific object `Job`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/#watch-job-v1-batch).

Enabling callbacks and listening to the API via `watch` will get you the same result as running:

```
$ kubectl get job example-job --watch -o json
```

So any changes to the object will be reflected as they happen, returning a JSON result that you can use later to feed your client.

Comment: so just to make it more clear. what i want is that the `pending` status should update once the job completes and should notify the user about the job completion. i have implemented the `job watcher` in my code but i am not sure if it's not doing what i want . i have added it in the question

Comment: Simply using the [`watch` method in the API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/#watch-job-v1-batch) (`GET /apis/batch/v1/watch/namespaces/{namespace}/jobs/{name}`) should stream the events comings from your job object. Then, you can use the Swagger callback to asynchronously listen to the events until you have your desired state.